# My fetch array is not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to pull an array to use on another query but it's not working, because the last comma.

```
    <?php
    include"connection.php";
    $pos = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM equipos");
    $logos = array();
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($pos)){
    $logos[] = "<br>'".$row['abrv']."'=>"."'".$row['logo']."'";
    }
    $logos = implode(",", $logos);

    $enjuego = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT * FROM partidos WHERE dprt='ftbls'");
    while($part=mysqli_fetch_array($enjuego)){
    $liga=$part['serie'];
    $eq1= $part['eq1'];
    $eq1s= strtoupper($eq1);
    $eq2= $part['eq2'];
    $eq2s= strtoupper($eq2);

    echo $logos[$eq1].'<br>';
    }
    ?>
```

It gives me the same error over and over again. 
This is the closest I came but just doesn’t  work.
Can someone tell me what  am I doing wrong?

The error I get is: Warning: Illegal string offset 'gua' in line 22

Comment: Have a look at [`implode`](http://php.net/implode).

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with your code:

- You never created an array
- You constantly overwrite `$logos`
- Your usage of `substr_replace()` indicates a deeper problem.

Here's a better approach:

1. Build the array.

   ```
   $logos = array();
   while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($pos)){
     $logos[] = "<br>'".$row['abrv']."'=>"."'".$row['logo']."'";
   }
   ```
2. There are many ways condense an array into a string. I encourage you to browse the manual on [PHP Array Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). In your case, you are interested in `implode()`

   ```
   $logos = implode(",", $logos);
   ```

**Note:** The value for `$logos` smells. You should construct your arrays to hold data, not formatting.

For example:

```
$logos[$row['abrv']] = $row['logo'];
```

Output:

```
print_r($logos);
```

Comment: Let’s see if I can explain myself: 
In one table I have a list of logos in that table there are two columns, c1=first 3 letter of the team and c2= Teams full name.
In another table I have a score for games to come and the teams name is in a column identical to c1 from table 1,  what I want to do is use the array from the first table to pull the logo for an image, so I figured something like this.
Array from Table 1 is $logos
And the row where the team name from the second table is $team1

<img  src=”foler/<?= $logos[$team1]?>”/>

Comment: I'm going crazy here... whay is this so dificult?

Comment: If you have a question about constructing your query, you should post another question. Each question should aim to solve one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved in many ways, but let's look at your code, there are quite a few things wrong in there.

- Semantically meaningless variable names like `pos`, `not`, `equipos`, `abrv`. Only `logo` and `result` are good variable names.
- Using the `*` selector in database queries. Don't do that, instead select the exact fields you need, it's better for performance, maintainability, code readability, testability, ... need I say more?
- Fetching per row and running code on each row when what you actually want is an array containing all rows. Solution:

  ```
  $result = mysqli_query($not, "SELECT * FROM equipos");
  $logos = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  ```
- Concatenating subarrays by using strings, that's not how it works, what you could do:

  ```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
      $logos[][$row['abrv']] = $row['logo'];
  }
  ```

  But as I said, that's not necessary.
- Overwriting your variable `$logos` with each iteration of the loop. You'd need to do `$logos[] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `implode` is useful for such cases.

Without knowing what exactly you want to do, take this as a first hint:

```
$logos = array();

while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($pos)){
    $logos[] = "<br>'".$row['abrv']."'=>"."'".$row['logo']."'";
}

$logos = implode(",", $logos);
```

Comment: Let’s see if I can explain myself:

In one table I have a list of logos in that table there are two columns, c1=first 3 letter of the team and c2= Teams full name.

In another table I have a score for games to come and the teams name is in a column identical to c1 from table 1, what I want to do is use the array from the first table to pull the logo for an image, so I figured something like this.


Array from Table 1 is $logos And the row where the team name from the second table is $team1...

<img src=”foler/<?= $logos[$team1]?>”/>

Comment: I’ve tried all suggestions from up there and it gives me an index problem

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I would have thought is just to change the query and fetch the array into that -

```
<?php
  include_once("connection.php");
  $result = mysqli_query($not,"SELECT abrv, logo FROM equipos");
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  // display the result
  echo "<pre>"
  print_r($rows);
  echo "</pre>"
?>
```

Comment: Too bad nobody could help whit this. Thanks for the suggestions, you all are berry nice people.